# URL com parametros string com angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, front-end, express.js

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de tratar url com parâmetros *string* em angular.js.

Ao ser acessado:

```
www.app.net/nomeDaPessoa/ServicoDaPessoa
```

Iria responder a uma determinada rota que esta recebendo o `nomeDaPessoa` e `ServicoDaPessoa` como parâmetro.

Outro exemplo seria:

```
www.app.net/nomeDaPessoa
```

No caso receberia como parâmetro o nomeDaPessoa!

Utilizo Node.js com Express.js para fazer a entrega dos arquivos.

Comment: Achei algo interessante para implementar o que você precisa: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par] Mais pro final ele explica o tratamento de rotas

Comment: Interessante esta opção Rafael, porem gostaria de não usar o # na url! Tentei com ui-route mas o mesmo utiliza o # nas url!

Comment: Fábio achei mais alguma coisa espero que ajude: [http://javascriptbrasil.com/tag/angularjs/]  ou [http://tableless.com.br/criando-uma-aplicacao-single-page-com-angularjs/]

Comment: O primeiro link me apontou um caminho, vou testar e se der certo posto aqui a solução! valew Rafael

Comment: Você ativou o `Html5Mode` no router?

Comment: Acho que não @mutlei!

Comment: Pra ativar, você faz uso da linha `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);` com o booleano apropriado, na `module.config` do `$locationProvider`.

Comment: Resolveu a questão Fábio?

Answer (score 1):

No [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.param) podes usar parametros deste modo:

```
app.get('/:nomeDaPessoa?/:ServicoDaPessoa?', function(req, res){
```

e depois obter esses parametros via `req.params`. Ou seja:

```
var nome = req.params.nomeDaPessoa;
var servico = req.params.ServicoDaPessoa;
```

Comment: Valew @Sergio, mas sabe me dizer como resolveria essa rota em Algular.js? Estive olhando o https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router porem não encontrei uma reposta para essa duvida!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver meu problema mas acho que não é a melhor forma!
Com base na resposta do Sergio e do Rafael criei um algoritmo:

Quando acessado via URL no node criei a rota que recebe esses parâmetros e salva em sessão o id dos mesmos assim:

```
router.get('/:nomeDaPessoa?/:ServicoDaPessoa?', function(req, res){
    var nome = req.params.nomeDaPessoa;
    var servico = req.params.ServicoDaPessoa;
    serviceController.getByUrl(nome, servico, function (data){
        req.session.serviceUrl = data.data[0].servico_id;
        req.session.professionalUrl = data.data[0].profissional_id;
        res.sendfile(FRONTEND_PATH + '/views/index.html');
    });
});
```

No front-end no angular criei a rota que para trazer a view correta:

```
.state('service', {
  url: '/:prof/:service',
  templateUrl: function ($stateParams){
    return '/views/detail.html';
  },
  controller: 'DetailController'
});
```

E em detailController valido se esta vindo a partir do clique na interface ou via URL, com isso vou ao node e pego os id's que estão na sessão:

```
if($rootScope.service && $rootScope.service.id){ //clicou em um servico na interface, nesse caso já tenho o id dos elementos!
    $scope.getDetailService($rootScope.service.id);
} else {
    Service.getSession(function(data){ //Vai ao node e pega o req.session
        $scope.getDetailService(data.servico_id);
    });
}
```

Bom como disse acho que não é a melhor forma mas resolver meu problema! se alguém tiver outra solução melhor me aviso! valew